# Wordpress generating wrong URLs

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a completely newbie in wordpress. At this moment, my blog URL is `blog.mysite.com`, and in the past it was `www.mysite.com/blog`.

The URLs and links are ok in the blog, because I changed the base URL in wp-config file. However, the images are still using the old route.

This is the URL of my pictures:

```
blog.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/canvas/functions/thumb.php?src=http://mysite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/bname-268x300.jpg&w=150&h=150&zc=1&q=90
```

As yoy can see, it is using TinThumb plugin, but the URL that it is using is the old one.

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress main drawbacks is it saves complete image url in db.
So if you migrating your site you have to search & replace url in your sql file & need to dump it again.

I suggest you to do it manually and follow the steps mention [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).

Also there is plugin available to do the same named [Search and Replace](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/).

Comment: I changed wp_posts table using the following tool: http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ but I am having the same problem.

Comment: Strange it should work. Though can you check your `site url` & `WordPress address url` is correct in wp-admin -> General Settings ?

Comment: Maybe I have to restart something?

Comment: Also try this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/ to replace your urls.

Comment: I tried replacing in all tables, not only in wp_posts and it worked

Answer (score 1):

add the two lines in wp-config

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://newsiteaddress.com/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://newsiteaddress.com/');
```

please note that some plugins that use the file system like ssome caches may have to be reconfigured or the cache may be reconfigured

Comment: I already did this.  "I changed the base URL in wp-config file".

Comment: having both lines does work for most sites (half a dozen so far). try updating permalinks and in last resort - export and re-import the wxr on a fresh install

Answer (score 1):

You need to dump database to file and replace all strings 'mysite.com/blog' to 'blog.mysite.com', and after overwrite database by fixed dump.
Sorry for my bad english.