# Update wordpress and plugins for a new address

Tags: wordpress

I change the URL of my website a couple months ago. Now when the older address goes way and I detected that the website is very slow. I found on source some references to the older address .

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.afetter.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_gallery_display/static/common.js?ver=3.8'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.afetter.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_gallery/static/slideshow/nextgen_basic_slideshow.js?ver=3.8'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.coelhophotos.net/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js?ver=3.8'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.coelhophotos.net/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?ver=3.8'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.coelhophotos.net/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/fancybox/nextgen_fancybox_init.js?ver=3.8'></script>
```

How I update the references ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress generating wrong URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895067/wordpress-generating-wrong-urls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a find&replace on your database, and there are many ways to do this.

Personally, i've tried and tested the [Wordpress Serialized PHP Search Tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) which uses a serialized approach to your data - as wordpress stores your data this way in the first place.

Simply upload the file, reference it on your website, i.e http://www.example.com/searchandreplace2.php

Put in your database creds if they don't find them automagically, and replace:

```
 Replace: http://www.coelhophotos.net/
 With: http://www.your-new-url.com/
```

Note the end slash, I have always put this in. I usually don't bother with the additional options, just do it vanilla.

*edit:*

You might want to manually set your `wp-config.php` to define the site url, incase..

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```